# Selecting Multiple table rows to edit in MVC4

Tags: c#, sql, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

So I'm creating a website with MVC4. Essentially what I have is a table of licenses, with a bunch of properties. I want to be able to add checkboxes to this table so that when you select a group of licenses and click the submit button it will allow you to bulk edit a select few properties of the selected licenses (for example, the issued dates on them). I can't seem to find an easy way to implement this.

Comment: As you are using checkbox, associate it to a bool property in your model. Then, when you'll post the form, just iterate in your posted model looking for the bool properties where value equals true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is an *easy* way to do this. However, I'll propose one solution.
The steps are:

1. There's one action sending a list of licenses to a view
2. The view presents them in a table and lets the use edit
3. The view **posts** this list to another action
4. This action receives all the licenses, editted or not

So, let's dig into it.

**Model**

```
public class License
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

**1st action**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<License> viewModel = new List<License>();
    viewModel.Add(new License() { Id = 1, Name = "Whatever" });
    viewModel.Add(new License() { Id = 2, Name = "Whatever else" });
    viewModel.Add(new License() { Id = 3, Name = "Nevermind this one" });

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Home"))
{
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Notes</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @{
                int i = 0;   
                foreach (MVC4.Test.Models.License l in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="licenses[@i].Id" readonly value="@l.Id"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="licenses[@i].Name" readonly value="@l.Name" class="_mayEdit" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="licenses[@i].Notes" readonly value="@l.Notes" class="_mayEdit"/></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="_edit" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    i++;
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('._edit').click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked'))
                $(this).parent().parents('tr').find('._mayEdit').removeAttr('readonly');
            else
                $(this).parent().parents('tr').find('._mayEdit').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
        });
    });
</script>
```

**2nd action**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(License[] licenses)
{
    return View();
}
```

A few things to note:

1. I'm using **jQuery**
2. Pay attention to that index when creating the inputs. It **must** start at 0 and increment by 1. This is the only way for the model binding understands that this is a collection of items
3. At the 2nd action, you may manipulate that list. Save it to a database or whatever.